User verification error due to security reasons when logging into Swagger
I want to do a simple authentication. For this, I added the necessary classes for spring security and jwt to my project. When I log in to Swagger to check the login process, it asks for username and password. While debugging, my code cannot find a user from the Customer Repository. And it throws Nullpointerexception
SecurityConfig Class
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
        this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/index.html", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

LoginController

@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider; 

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            loginRequest.getUsername(),
                            loginRequest.getPassword()
                    )
            );

            String jwtToken = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(loginRequest.getUsername());

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(jwtToken);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("Invalid credentials");
        }
    }

    static class LoginRequest {
        private String username;
        private String password;

        // Getters and setters
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}

MyUserDetailsService Class

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired

    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (customer == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user with username: " + username);
        }
        return new User(customer.getUsername(), customer.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());

    }
}

When I open my Swagger page, the debug comes to this line: Customer customer = customerRepository.findByUsername(username);
And here it cannot find a user via db. But my user is added in the db. I've run the same query in other methods before. and found the desired user. But after adding security it gives an error. Should there be a default user here, not the user in the db?
